# Unable to convert Data in shared preference as List In Flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to save user details in shared preference in flutter. And trying to generate a qr code from it.

I have assigned the key in shared preference as a string list,but when I try to return the string list and assign it to a list,so that I can send it to the qr generator function, it throws an error,

"type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'List' "

My code is as follows

```
  _read() async {
    print("reading stored data");
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    // read
    final myStringList = prefs.getStringList('my_string_list_key') ?? [];
    print(myStringList);
    return myStringList;
  }
```

Calling function

```
 onPressed: () {
setState((){
var _user_details = new List(3);
_user_details = _read();
                      _dataString=_user_details[0]+"/n"+_user_details[1]+"/n"+_user_details[2];
print(_dataString);
_inputErrorText = null;
});
},
```

Comment: `_user_details = await _read();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your async call in `onPressed` before refreshing by `setState`

```dart
onPressed: () async {
  var _user_details = await _read();
  setState(() {
    // you might check _user_details is null or something here...
    _dataString = _user_details[0]+"/n"+_user_details[1]+"/n"+_user_details[2];
    print(_dataString);
    _inputErrorText = null;
  });
},
```

Please be noticed, you should check your `_user_details` is null or unecpected format (ex. length < 3).